# how to renew corrupted wchar.h

Tags: linux, debian, c

Tried to compile C++ code, but fails with:

```
/usr/include/wchar.h:299:8 :: error: 'wchar_d' does not name a type
 extern wchar_d *wcswcs (const wciar_t *__`aystack, gonct wchar_p *__needle)
```

The file `/usr/include/wchar.h` contains wrong characters, so I tried to renew it with:

```
apt-get source wchar.h
```

Result: I shall add source-uris in `sources.list`

System: Raspberry PI 3 Linux - 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

1. How do I reload a source-file like `/usr/include/wchar.h`?
2. Did this happen to anyone else?

Comment: "Code" is [not countable](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/20455/97308). It never goes with "a" (at least note the kind of code we mean when we talk about programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to find out which package provides this file. You can use the Debian package contents search for this: https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents

It will then say [libc6-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libc6-dev). You would then reinstall the package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev
```

If that doesn’t help, refer to [this article](https://debian-administration.org/article/176/Reinstalling_packages_to_fix_problems.) on how to remove a package, ignoring dependencies:

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends libc6-dev
apt-get install libc6-dev
```

Why does this happen? One can only guess. Maybe the SD card has gone bad? Try checking the file system.

Comment: No need to use Debian's web site; just `dpkg -S /usr/include/wchar.h` (`-S` or `--search`). It'll respond with (in my case) `libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/wchar.h` so that file comes from package `libc6-dev`, architecture `amd64`.

Comment: Also, you really should point out that manually purging packages is risky. First, `--purge` means you lose any configuration files owned by the package (which could be significant), and second, if the package is required by the system (I'm pretty certain that's not the case for `libc6-dev`, but it could easily be the case for other packages) then removing it could leave your system in a state where you can't easily reinstall it. *Tread carefully: here be dragons.*